# Make a function parameter required in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```
type NoArg = {
  (): void
}

type OneArg = {
  (x:number): void
}

let noArg: NoArg = (x:number)=>{}
let oneArg: OneArg = ()=>{}
```

Only the first assigned generates a compiler error.  I understand why this is the case, because JavaScript allows functions to be passed with less than their complete set of possible arguments, and that’s different than saying the arguments are optional which has to do with how the function is *called* rather than how it’s *passed*. See [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).

But that said, is there any way to construct a version of the OneArg interface that will *not* be compatible with a zero argument function?

I understand this can be done via branding or nominal typing, e.g.,

```
type OneArg = {
  (x:number): void
  _brand: “OneArg”
}
```

But that, or any other type of nominal typing solution, requires doing extra work on assignment (e.g., you have to explicitly add the _brand property to the function).

So my question is—is there any way to construct a type NoArg that will fail the simple assignment `let oneArg: OneArg = ()=>{}`?

The FAQ linked above says “There is currently not a way in TypeScript to indicate that a callback parameter must be present.“ Does that completely rule out what I want to do here?  I’m hoping it doesn’t since this isn’t a callback parameter, but perhaps the rationale is the same.

UPDATE: In the comments below, a question was raised as to whether this could be achieved with a type guard test.  The answer, as far as I can tell, is no, because the type overlap means the type guard won't narrow the types.  You can see it in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhAggJwOZQLxQN4CgpQAUAHgFxwCuAtgEYTICUpUAbgPYCWAJrgL665QkKABUA7mxToseAgRLlqdZABooIUgGdgyDnFRNWnHv1wAbCMChsEUzETKVa9BhgB82fhavAJdrApOymoa2rr6rh6mAMY22lAcmvBIaPaEAGYUcNGkyVIAPuKSaIaZ2QmasLap7lBl0QB0FvrAABZQADxYAIwC9cAcNlBcidG6VHoAhsBsyIRUIABiWTlVKej5on4lOPhyAPT7IuDQqBSTyFxQrfQQajQUwA3PewQc6YSJeWjzSysMDF2cmBUGQlgoyDgUAWy2yryg-GBEDMmmgshBBDBwAhUJhK3h-FMhygzwaIgAylA2noANaVGhsNrWdJUm6oqAXaBCaBFKS4WJweILerdewjTRjDgTODTWaEGzrBj8uJWYUrABMYtG4ymMzmvmKBiAA).

Comment: Your title (which doesn't need the tag TypeScript in it) asks a different question from the body of the post. The title asks about differentiation between two functions with different arity, whereas the body of the post asks about making an argument "required", in essence. You may want to amend one or the other.

Comment: I meant to ask the question in the body.  I'd welcome any suggestions on how to improve the title, but i'm not totally sure I understand the difference.  If you have an idea for how to make it more precise, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I would really like to see a real world use case for that benefits from this behavior.

Comment: Well, my use case is a function that takes functions in either the format (state) => {//function} or (state, ...args) => {//function} and converts them into functions for use in the useSelector() react-redux hook, which only allows the (state)=> {} form.  In the case of the first type, my function passes them on, in the case of the second it converts them to curried functions so ...args is captured in the closure of the useSelector()-acceptable format.  To do this in a type-safe way, I need to be able to "tell" TS which functions have more than one argument.  For now, I'm using nominal types.

Comment: To continue... this is basically to support an internal extension of redux toolkit we are using to allow people to write slice-specific selectors without needing to worry about proper currying.  FWIW, the nominal typing approach works fine, but it requires the use of additional constructor functions to apply the branding.

Comment: I don't think you need to be worried about this because typescript won't allow you to call that function without any arguments

Comment: @sam256 How do you tell at runtime which functions are which?

Comment: all javascript functions have an instance property length that tells you the number of arguments expected by the function.  so for function myFunc, I just test if myFunc.length === 1.

Comment: @sam256 that's interesting. Couldn't you just test for `f.length <= 1` though?

Comment: @aluan-haddad, you mean put that in type guard? the problem is because of the fact that the multi-argument signature includes the single argument signature, TS won't narrow them with a type guard--it will always give you the multi-argument type.  i have a playground that shows this, which i've now added to the original post.

Comment: I didn't mean in a type guard at all. You said _"In the case of the first type, my function passes them on"_, and if you are doing that based on the property `length` property, you can just treat `length === 0` and `length === 1` in the same way. Too bad you can't post a link

Comment: i added the link to the original post now.  i think i'm not following the point you are making, though.  in the actual implementation i'm distinguishing between length 1 and length >1.  it's not problem from a JS perspective, but the issue is if input function.length 1 i want to get "vanilla function" typing on the output function but if it's >1 I want to get "curry function" typing.  that's easy to do with conditional types _if_ I can indicate to TS which type I have on the input, but I can't because of the overlap issue indicated in the playground.

Comment: [working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhAggJwOZQLxQN4CgoFQAUAHgFxRwCuAtgEYTICUFAbgPYCWAJrgL65coSFAAqAd3Yp0WPIWLkodduwA2EAIZwANFBAUAzsGSc4qFlA49+g9cCjsE0zAorV6jJpgB8OKALsoYElnLFIKZTVNHT1DY1NzHz8BXABjRyMoTgN4JDQXIgAzKjhUilznAB8xELQLYtKsg1gnfIxfBtSAOnUzYAALKAAeLABGIXBoCrQYZAkpNpa89Gr56QBuXE7gTkcobmzUkxpTDWB2ZCIaEAAxErKl6Vm1upx8QgB6D9FJqFQqDTIbhQfqMCC6OhUYBdGHvAicQrEbLTVBXW73JheOTyQjICDAKjIOBQa53UpEUZMTbyATyCCqAzQbE4qB4glEkno8mFDQM8FQADkBgFVLh-hsuC+UBhXVEAGUgv1TABrZrKAYOREDCCMqCA6DCaAvVBpDL2a6dUYuA4GI6cE5wM4XIiOZZMU1wTIW+4AJmth2Op3Ol2CC3MQA)

Comment: The return type of `discriminator` would always be `OneArg | TwoArg` because you just return the function in both branches. But, in your test case, the type `OneArg | TwoArg` _is_ precisely the type `TwoArg`.

Comment: And even then, [narrowing still works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhAggJwOZQLxQBQA8BcUcArgLYBGEyAlJgHxQBuA9gJYAmAUJ6JFACoB3ZinRY8hEhSoAaKCEIBnYMlZxUtDAxYduAGwjAozBKMw4CRMpRr0oAbygBfTgaPBhZ8Zak25CqGVVdU0GRxdOAGMTZShWRXgkNHNsADNCRLMAHwFPNGpCVLjFWFNkrShUgDoDdWAACygAHiwARm5U4jhI4FYTKHZ4yNVSNQBDYGZkNIyy9ByhEXyHTig1qGRDYmQ4Ysy0NNoAfkrsVtpCs7kAckVr6gBuThcgA)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221184/discussion-between-sam256-and-aluan-haddad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with @aluan-haddad, I have a partial solution.  I can't get exactly what I asked for, i.e., an "automatic" type definition that distinguishes between a function with the required parameter and one without, but I have come up with a "discriminator" function that will distinguish between the two functions and apply an appropriate branded type.

The solution relies on using a conditional type, coupled with the fact that the one-argument function is incompatible with the zero-argument type (even though the reverse is not true), to coerce the correct types.

```
type NoArg = {
    _brand: 'NoArg'
    ():void
}

type OneArg = {
  _brand: 'OneArg'
  (x:number): void
}

// Correct typings
let noArg: NoArg = discriminator(()=>{})
let oneArg: OneArg = discriminator((x:number)=>{})

// Both of these error, as hoped!
let noArgError: NoArg = discriminator((x:number)=>{})
let oneArgError: OneArg = discriminator(()=>{})

function discriminator<T extends (x:any)=>any>(myFunc: T) {
    let discriminatedFunc
    if(myFunc.length === 0) {
        discriminatedFunc = {
            _brand: 'NoArg',
            myFunc
        }
    } 
    else {
        discriminatedFunc = {
            _brand: 'OneArg',
            myFunc
        }
    }
    return discriminatedFunc as unknown as T extends ()=>any ? NoArg : OneArg
}
```

And on [a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gQQE4HMoF4oG8BQV9QD6ARkgIYB2AJgFxQDk8yK9eBAFAJQ0BucAllRwBfHDlCQoAeQoRmGbGxLlqdejLmpW%20dgA8aFAK4BbYhCTcofQSLEB6O1ADCcJEggBjYFAn8KKAGccABsIbwpEVDomVAUqfgCPJH5jPzJgV3YudAA%20LGFOELCoOFlmOg15THjE5NSKdMy9AxMzC1z8wpwHKAAhOGAACxKAMx9BiADocyRXABooMgCoQbhIKgBCIvDIlABRN1do3biEpJS0jKQs-SNTc04Ogu2SstQD2aQKt7Rqs7rLk1HnlnjgRoYKF5%20KUoDVzvVGkgADwAFSgEF0wAg1GWzUoIGB%20Jy7GMIAAYhCPHQUZxFAQoKFvHCAQ0sVQKZC2Ph%20CMSeTKQA6UL%20IYYdCYAAMtNw9PpzIurIg7MpChlsvVykotAYMRYcy56oIpI5HgN9NE5qgBogwSmdMN8oRbJNqrNhs1qgYlS0%20sNsuNlLd%20AtBBD%20HcwEMSAosP%20CvSSpdSygEIA1hEAO4x5NojFYnFQbI5fFQAD8sBO300KBEQA).

NB: To my point that this is relying on the one argument function being incompatible with the zero type function, note that the reverse version of the conditional type `T extends (x:number)=>any ? OneArg : NoArg` will not work, because it always resolves to OneArg.

Now, is this better than "branding" the functions in the first place via constructor functions?  I think so, because you only need one discriminator function vs two branding functions.  And also because you don't necessarily need to know the signatures of your functions ex-ante, i.e., when you pass them to the discriminator.

Anyone see any problems with this solution?  Is there a better one, or is this all TS permits?